# How to make table real table

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create table like this http://cdn5.staztic.com/cdn/screenshot/booleancalc-13-2.jpg (can't post images because I'm new). Which layout should I use? I thought about TableLayout, but I didn't find a way to use vertical and horizontal dividers at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify white background for your table and black background for your cells. Each cell should have n pixels margin (depending how wide you want your borders be).